# Android Studio : buildTypes block won't collapse in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, build.gradle, code-formatting

I was having the *`buildTypes (and other things) cannot be applied to groovy.lang.Closure`* error earlier - Now fixed by switching to default gradle wrapper in settings.

But, after i changed to default gradle wrapper a strange thing started. I **cannot collapse** the `buildTypes` block in my `build.gradle` in Android Studio. (v 1.5.1)

I can collapse every other block like `productFlavors`, `dependencies`, `defaultConfig` but just not `buildTypes`. Check screenshot below:

[image]

Even right-clicking with the cursor on the `buildTypes` keyword and selecting `Folding -> Collapse` isn't working.

My `build.gradle` is slightly huge with a lot of flavors and configurations for each and i really like to keep everything collapsed and expand only parts i need to view or edit.

Anyone knows why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, Funny thing. I just had to close and reopen the file and it started behaving normal. Generally never close this file so did not think of this before.

[image]